# Javascript button click has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, button

I have a asp button that I want to be clicked by a javascript function when I click a regular html button. However when it gets to the button.click() there is no effect whatsoever. If I look in the debugger, everything else in the function acts as normal, and if I click on the asp button myself it runs the code I expect it to or if I call the joingameBtn_Click in the console it also properly clicks the button. I created the buttons dynamically on page load in a loop so that each has an onclick function that passes an id unique to it.

```
function joinGameBtn_Click(campaignid) {
   var temp = document.getElementById('CampaignID');
   temp.value = campaignid;

   var button = document.getElementById("CampaignBtn");
   button.click();
}

function createFunction(id) {
    return function() { joinGameBtn_Click(id); };
}

//Where the button is created
var hoverbutton = document.createElement('button');
hoverbutton.id = 'hoverbutton';
var func = createFunction(campId);
hoverbutton.onclick = func;
```

After reading some other posts I saw that sometimes the dynamically created buttons could be the problem in that the event listener isn't tied to them. Some suggestions mentioned making sure the document was ready so I tried this as well to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#hoverbutton', function () {
    $("#CampaignBtn").click();
   });
});
```

EDIT: Here is the asp.net button in question.

```
  <asp:Button ID="CampaignBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none;"  OnClick="joinGame_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Here is the server side button click function:

```
    public void joinGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["campaignid"] = int.Parse(CampaignID.Value);
        Response.Redirect("CampaignSession.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: you are creating a function which when fired, returns a function.

Comment: that's a relic from a previous version that I never changed back

Comment: Can you post the html for the one of the buttons in question?

Comment: The buttons are created in the javascript above, I can add the generated html when the page is loaded if you want. I went ahead and added the asp.net button that I am trying to click.

Comment: You are creating multiple of those buttons dynamically correct?  One problem is they all have the same ID.  Another (possibly) is the onClick method `OnClick="joinGame_Click"`.  Is that function in your js?

Comment: Ah good catch - I went ahead and fixed the id issue, but that unfortunately did not fix it. The joinGame_Click is in the server side code, I will add that into the question

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the console as this happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: can you make a JS Fiddle?

Comment: Does you `#hoverbutton` element have the same issue the `#CampaignBtn` had in terms of repeating the same id value?  How many of the hoverbuttons are there?  Can you post the html for that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my asp button to a regular html button which seemed to resolve the issue

```
<button onserverclick="joinGame_Click" runat="server" id="CampaignBtn" ClientIDMode="Static">Button</button>
```

Not sure if fixing the issues with duplicate id's played a role in it as well.